# Is there an equivalent of $` in Javascript's `replace()` for Python's re.sub()?

Tags: python

[In JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter), you can use

- `` $` ``  Inserts the portion of the string that precedes the matched substring.
- `$'`  Inserts the portion of the string that follows the matched substring.

To get the substring before and after the match.

Is there an equivalent of this in Python's `re.sub()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a replacement string, you can pass a function to `re.sub`. The function will receive a match object, and should return the replacement for the match.

Within the function, you can use [`match.start()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.start) and [`match.end()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.end) to get the start and end indices of the match in the original string, and [`match.string`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.string) to get the original string passed to `re.sub`. Thus,

```
match.string[:match.start()]
```

gives the effect of `` $` ``, and

```
match.string[match.end():]
```

gives the effect of `$'`.